# How can I allow certain people to see all list items without edit permission?

Tags: permissions, custom-form, list-item, edit, read-only

So I have this issue with specific permissions. What I want is that certain people (not users, administration staff) can view all items of the custom list, but cannot edit them or delete them. On advanced settings I have that users can add items and can only see and edit their own items. If i give administation permissions to read and view items, the advanced seetings does not allow them to see the custom list items. Only way i can allow them to see them,all list items if I give them full control, but this also allows them to edit and delete items as well as. I tried many things but I was unsuccesfull. Are there any ways I can grant the right permissions without a code?

Comment: I am on SharePoint 2013.

Comment: This is for SP 2013 settings -Have you tried Restricted Contribute that means the users can add edit but not delete.. Go to Site Collection level - Site Permission - Permission Level - Add permission level  and create new permissions called restricted contribute and Uncheck this Box -  Delete Items  -  Delete items from a list and documents from a document library. content thus restricting them from deleting any content but still be able to add and edit .Let me know if that helps

Comment: This unfortunately does nto work, because of the advanced setting. If i have advanced setting to be set up that item level permissions are: Read items that are created by the user and create and edit own items only.

Comment: Up till now I found that only way i can allow administration to view list items, is either if I remove advance detting item level permissions or if I give full control.

Answer (score 1):

First You can assign Read permission to the users whom you want to only view the items and not add modify or delete. IF you want the users to add items but not edit or delete any item then Create a Custom Permission Level by going into Site Settings-->Site permission--> Permission Levels--> Add a permission level. Here select the action item you want the user to have. Once the permission level is created.. assign the same to the users.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not give right permissions. Till now I found that I either have to removed item-level permissions or give full control. However neither option is actually what I need.

Comment: I believe you are doing something wrong.. The scenario which you have asked is achievable. If you give read permission to a list and library, user will be seeing all items in that particular library.

Comment: Yes they would, if in advanced settings choose to allow users to see all items. But if I want users to see their own items only, administration people will not see list items. As I want users to see their own items, administration to have read only permissions and be able to see full list, the only way this seems to work with advanced permissions on, is if administration has full control.